Monotonic percentiles of the Beta distribution wrt mean?
Consider the implicit equation for the percentiles $p$ of the Beta distribution with fixed $q\in(0,1)$:
$$
q=\frac{B(p,\alpha,\beta)}{B(\alpha,\beta)},
$$
where the numerator and denominator are the incomplete and complete Beta functions. Consider the case $\alpha>1$, $\beta>1$ where the distribution is unimodular.
The parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be expressed with the mean $\mu$ and variance $v$ (see link above). I would like to show, if at all possible, that the percentile $p(q,\mu,v)$ is an increasing function of the mean
$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial\mu}>0
$$
ps.: this is trivially true for the normal distribution where all percentiles shift with the mean, irrespective of variance. I was wondering if it can be shown for Beta too. I tried to manipulate the above expression with Maple but eventually gave up, there were too many hypergeometric functions involved.
